# Dynamicaly building table from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I've been trying to get this code to work for a few hours now and can't seem to figure out what i am doing wrong or what i might have messed up, I copied this code from a example page that works and modified it to make the table i am wanting to build..

**Original Cliped Code:**

```
$(function () {
            var $wrap = $('<div>').attr('id', 'tableWrap');
            var $tbl = $('<table>').attr('id', 'basicTable');

            for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
                $tbl.append($('<tr>').append($('<td>').text(i),$('<td>').text(200 - i)));
            }

            $wrap.append($tbl);
            $('body').append($wrap);
        });
```

now that I changed it to six rows, and loading links and data from javascript array it doesn't build the table for some reason..

**My Code:**

```
myArray = new Array();
    myArray[0] = new Array("001","Title","http://www.google.com/","https://www.google.com/images/logos/google_logo_41.png");
    myArray[1] = new Array("002","Title","http://www.google.com/","https://www.google.com/images/logos/google_logo_41.png");
    myArray[2] = new Array("003","Title","http://www.google.com/","https://www.google.com/images/logos/google_logo_41.png");
    myArray[3] = new Array("004","Title","http://www.google.com/","https://www.google.com/images/logos/google_logo_41.png");
    myArray[4] = new Array("005","Title","http://www.google.com/","https://www.google.com/images/logos/google_logo_41.png");
    myArray[5] = new Array("006","Title","http://www.google.com/","https://www.google.com/images/logos/google_logo_41.png");
    myArray[6] = new Array("007","Title","http://www.google.com/","https://www.google.com/images/logos/google_logo_41.png");
    myArray[7] = new Array("008","Title","http://www.google.com/","https://www.google.com/images/logos/google_logo_41.png");
    myArray[8] = new Array("009","Title","http://www.google.com/","https://www.google.com/images/logos/google_logo_41.png");
    myArray[9] = new Array("010","Title","http://www.google.com/","https://www.google.com/images/logos/google_logo_41.png");


    var $wrap = $('<div>').attr('id', 'tableWrap');              
    var $tbl = $('<table>').attr('id', 'basicTable'); 

    for(i=0;i<myArray.length;i++){
        $(function () {                                   
            $tbl.append($('<tr>').append(
                        $('<td>').text('<a href="'+myArray[i][2]+'" target="_new"><img src="'+myArray[i][3]+'" alt="'+myArray[i][1]'"></a>'),
                        $('<td>').text('<a href="'+myArray[i][2]+'" target="_new"><img src="'+myArray[i][3]+'" alt="'+myArray[i][1]'"></a>'),
                        $('<td>').text('<a href="'+myArray[i][2]+'" target="_new"><img src="'+myArray[i][3]+'" alt="'+myArray[i][1]'"></a>'),
                        $('<td>').text('<a href="'+myArray[i][2]+'" target="_new"><img src="'+myArray[i][3]+'" alt="'+myArray[i][1]'"></a>'),
                        $('<td>').text('<a href="'+myArray[i][2]+'" target="_new"><img src="'+myArray[i][3]+'" alt="'+myArray[i][1]'"></a>'),
                        $('<td>').text('<a href="'+myArray[i][2]+'" target="_new"><img src="'+myArray[i][3]+'" alt="'+myArray[i][1]'"></a>')));             
        }              
        $wrap.append($tbl);             
        $('#c').append($wrap);         
    });
```

In the body i have a..

```
 <div id="c"></div>
```

that i'm trying to load it into... i'm wanting to stick with jquery, but almost tempted to just use javascript document.write functions

**----  UPDATE 05/14/2012  ----**
Thanks to alot of help from many people, it has come down to using just JavaScript for now. Have it working and doing as I need it to for now, until i get back from vacation. I would still like to compress/convert it to jquery, so it looks cleaner and already using it for other things. So for anyone who has ran across this post and that is looking for something in this direction here's the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WRgjv/371/) I tossed together to help show how i set it up from everyone's help.... THANKS AGAIN EVERYONE!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function () {      
    var $wrap = $('<div/>').attr('id', 'tableWrap');              
    var $tbl = $('<table/>').attr('id', 'basicTable');

    for(i=0;i<myArray.length;i++){
            //  $(function () { is miss placed                     
            $tbl.append($('<tr/>').append(
                        $('<td/>').html('<a href="'+myArray[i][2]+'" target="_new"><img src="'+myArray[i][3]+'" alt="'+myArray[i][1]+'"></a>'),
                        $('<td/>').html('<a href="'+myArray[i][2]+'" target="_new"><img src="'+myArray[i][3]+'" alt="'+myArray[i][1]+'"></a>'),
                        $('<td/>').html('<a href="'+myArray[i][2]+'" target="_new"><img src="'+myArray[i][3]+'" alt="'+myArray[i][1]+'"></a>'),
                        $('<td/>').html('<a href="'+myArray[i][2]+'" target="_new"><img src="'+myArray[i][3]+'" alt="'+myArray[i][1]+'"></a>'),
                        $('<td/>').html('<a href="'+myArray[i][2]+'" target="_new"><img src="'+myArray[i][3]+'" alt="'+myArray[i][1]+'"></a>'),
                        $('<td/>').html('<a href="'+myArray[i][2]+'" target="_new"><img src="'+myArray[i][3]+'" alt="'+myArray[i][1]+'"></a>')));             
        }              
        $wrap.append($tbl);             
        $('#c').append($wrap);         
    });
```

**PROBLEM**

1. Miss place of `$(function) {..`
2. `alt="'+myArray[i][1]'"` should be `alt="'+myArray[i][1]+'"`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/WRgjv/95/)**

Comment: i've tried it in both places and it still doesn't load... could it be with the array's?  [link]http://jsfiddle.net/WRgjv/93/

Comment: ahh crap i hate when i miss the little things liek the   +  sign... ahh i see what i was missing, one question though, why does the <td> have to have the <td/> in it?... btw thanks for the help on this

Comment: @acrichm good practice. you can also u `$(td)`/`$(tr)` like so and should use these.

Comment: k awesome thanks for the tips, will definitely remember them.. thanks for all the help

Comment: thecodeparadox, something i was trying today, just wondering; to create different images in each td i took out all but one $(<td/>).... changed the for loop to while(i<6)... to create 6 columns now instead of $tbl.append i tried $tr.append that didn't seem to work. so will i have to do something totally different? i searched Google and tried different variations and those didn't work for me, and just confused me more then what i was when i posted this thread

Answer (score 1):

First, you forgot to close `table` element after `for` statement

Second, why `$(function() {` after `for` ? Is wrong. If would use this, you have to close it with `});`

```
var $wrap = $('<div>').attr('id', 'tableWrap');              
    var $tbl = $('<table>').attr('id', 'basicTable'); 

    for(i=0;i<myArray.length;i++){                                 
            $tbl.append($('<tr>').append(
                        $('<td>').text('<a href="'+myArray[i][2]+'" target="_new"><img src="'+myArray[i][3]+'" alt="'+myArray[i][1]'"></a>'),
                        $('<td>').text('<a href="'+myArray[i][2]+'" target="_new"><img src="'+myArray[i][3]+'" alt="'+myArray[i][1]'"></a>'),
                        $('<td>').text('<a href="'+myArray[i][2]+'" target="_new"><img src="'+myArray[i][3]+'" alt="'+myArray[i][1]'"></a>'),
                        $('<td>').text('<a href="'+myArray[i][2]+'" target="_new"><img src="'+myArray[i][3]+'" alt="'+myArray[i][1]'"></a>'),
                        $('<td>').text('<a href="'+myArray[i][2]+'" target="_new"><img src="'+myArray[i][3]+'" alt="'+myArray[i][1]'"></a>'),
                        $('<td>').text('<a href="'+myArray[i][2]+'" target="_new"><img src="'+myArray[i][3]+'" alt="'+myArray[i][1]'"></a>')));             
        }              
  $tbl.append("</table">);
```

Comment: I was trying it in both places just to see if that was the cause of it not showing, the the `$tbl.append("</table>");` didn't think i would have to have it in there that jquery would close it for me since this worked for this site where i got the code from http://ajondeck.net/post/2010/06/24/jQuery-Dynamically-Create-Table.aspx